# assembly multi modules maven project in a single jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a parent maven project that includes some child projects and a build/assembly project. The structure looks like this, where the buildProj does not contain any class

```
ParentProj
    + pom.xml 
    + ChildProj1
        ++   pom.xml
    + ChildProj2
     ++   pom.xml
    + buildProj
     ++   pom.xml
```

this is the pom.xml of the buildProj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gr1</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildproj</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gr1</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChildProj1</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gr1</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChildProj2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.bonanza.CabalImpl</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>



</project>
```

nevertheless when I do `mvn package`, the jar of the buildProj is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add under the version tag

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**Later edit**
If you are using the assembly plugin you should also have the assembly XML

src/assembly/bin.xml

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<formats>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>${artifact}</include>
        </includes>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${artifact}</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

and to package it

```
mvn clean package assembly:single
```

also here your updated pom

```
<build>
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <archive>
                  <manifest>
                     <mainClass>com.bonanza.CabalImpl</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
               </archive>
               <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>make-assembly</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: is It possible to have the jar name as the same artifactId instead of *jar-with-dependencies ?

Comment: in the assembly configuration add <finalName>myFinalName</finalName> it might show you an error but it works

Comment: also, add this one <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> too to ignore the assembly generated id

Comment: I only would like to include only the classes from the /src folder from each module, but also includes all the jars (logging, etc..)

Comment: you can try to add those in the <includes> tag or to add the ones you want exclude under the <excludes> tag